# Converting a latin string to unicode in python

Tags: python, unicode, scrapy, latin

I am working o scrapy, I scraped some sites and stored the items from  the scraped page in to json files, but some of them are containing the following format.

```
l = ["Holding it Together",
     "Fowler RV Trip",
     "S\u00e9n\u00e9gal - Mali - Niger","H\u00eatres et \u00e9tang",
     "Coll\u00e8ge marsan","N\u00b0one",
     "Lines through the days 1 (Arabic) \u0633\u0637\u0648\u0631 \u0639\u0628\u0631 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u064a\u0627\u0645 1",
     "\u00cdndia, Tail\u00e2ndia &amp; Cingapura"]
```

I can expect that the list consists of different format, but i want to convert that and store the strings in the list with their original names like below

```
l = ["Holding it Together",
     "Fowler RV Trip",
     "Lines through the days 1 (Arabic) سطور عبر الأيام 1 | شمس الدين خ | Blogs"         ,
     "Índia, Tailândia & Cingapura "]
```

Thanks in advance...........

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have byte strings containing unicode escapes. You can convert them to unicode with the `unicode_escape` codec:

```
>>> print "H\u00eatres et \u00e9tang".decode("unicode_escape")
Hêtres et étang
```

And you can encode it back to byte strings:

```
>>> s = "H\u00eatres et \u00e9tang".decode("unicode_escape")
>>> s.encode("latin1")
'H\xeatres et \xe9tang'
```

You can filter and decode the non-unicode strings like:

```
for s in l: 
    if not isinstance(s, unicode): 
        print s.decode('unicode_escape')
```

Comment: Thanks and i got exact answer.

Comment: but what if the list has unicode strings like l = [u'Holding it Together', u'Fowler RV Trip' ..... ]

Comment: Actually i had that strings as unicode strings in the list when i run this command i am getting this error                "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)"

Comment: @shivakrishna See my updated answer how to encode back to byte strings, but this might fail with Arabic letters. What is exactly the problem if you have already Unicode?

Comment: @shivakrishna Or do you have mixed strings? Unicode and byte? In this case you can filter them with `isinstance(s, unicode)` or just catch the `UnicodeDecodeError`...

Comment: can u provide an example of how to filter them.

Comment: @shivakrishna See above for an example

Answer (score 1):

> i want to convert that and store the strings in the list with their original names like below

When you serialise to JSON, there may be a flag that allows you to turn off the escaping of non-ASCII characters to `\u` sequences. If you are using the standard library `json` module, it's `ensure_ascii`:

```
>>> print json.dumps(u'Índia')
"\u00cdndia"
>>> print json.dumps(u'Índia', ensure_ascii= False)
"Índia"
```

However be aware that with that safety measure taken away you now have to be able to deal with non-ASCII characters in a correct way, or you'll get a bunch of `UnicodeError`s. For example if you are writing the JSON to a file you must explicitly encode the Unicode string to the charset you want (for example UTF-8).

```
j= json.dumps(u'Índia', ensure_ascii= False)
open('file.json', 'wb').write(j.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Thanks for u r answer, i got exact answer what i am expecting, actually i want to display the strings(without escaping non ascii characters) in to json files. Now by the above code i got the output thanks once again.

Comment: It is suggested to always write unicode data to a file with the `codecs` module. See http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html Downvote is for file operations without safely closing. Never give a bad example.