# Convert a unicode string to its original format

Tags: python, list, unicode-string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting a latin string to unicode in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750420/converting-a-latin-string-to-unicode-in-python)

I have a list with the following format after storing in a file

```
list_example = [
         u"\u00cdndia, Tail\u00e2ndia &amp; Cingapura",
         u"Lines through the days 1 (Arabic) \u0633\u0637\u0648\u0631 \u0639\u0628\u0631 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u064a\u0627\u0645 1",
]
```

But the actual format of the strings in the list is

```
actual_format = [
         "Índia, Tailândia & Cingapura ",
         "Lines through the days 1 (Arabic) سطور عبر الأيام 1 | شمس الدين خ "
]
```

How can I convert the strings in `list_example` to strings present in the `actual_format` list?

Comment: The format is already right... Try `print list_example[1]`

Comment: Note: you made need to `.encode()` `list_example[1]` to an encoding your terminal understands, depending on your locale settings.

Comment: But i am getting the follwoing error when i tried

Comment: [i.decode('unicode-escape') for i in list_example]

Comment: "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xcd' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear to me. In any case, the following guidelines should help you solving your problem.

If you define those strings in a Python source code, then you should

- know in which character encoding your editor saves the source code file (e.g. utf-8)
- declare that encoding in the first line of your source file, via e.g. `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`
- define those strings as unicode objects:

`strings = [u"Índia, Tailândia & Cingapura ", u"Lines through the days 1 (Arabic) سطور عبر الأيام 1 | شمس الدين خ "]`

(Note: in Python 3, literal strings are unicode objects by default, i.e. you don't need the `u`. In Python 2, unicode strings are of type `unicode`, in Python 3, unicode strings are of type `string`.)

When you then want to save those strings to a file, you should explicitly define the character encoding:

```
with open('filename', 'w') as f:
    s = '\n'.join(strings)
    f.write(s.encode('utf-8'))
```

When you then want to read those strings again from that file, you again have to explicitly define the character encoding in order to decode the file contents properly:

```
with open('filename') as f:
    strings = [l.decode('utf-8') for line in f]
```

Comment: You should write/read from files with the `codecs` module, if unicode is involved. For example `with codecs.open('test', encoding='utf-8', mode='w')`. See the Unicode HOWTO for details: http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html

Comment: Yes, that is a very convenient module. However, the goal of my answer was that shiva grasps the encode/decode essentials. Therefore, I won't modify the answer, okay? :)

Answer (score 1):

```
actual_format = [x.decode('unicode-escape') for x in list_example]
```

Comment: But when i run the above command i am getting the follwing error "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xcd' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)"